# Nested class definition and generic returns in C++

Tags: c++, generics, multiset

I'm trying to convert a large Java project to C++ and have a lot of Java experience and the polymorphisms have gotten reasonably complicated. I've done some research and learning about C++ templates but haven't really gotten it to work yet. I'm translating the following code

```
class Entity {
    abstract class InputType<T extends Entity> implements Comparator<TreeMultiset<? extends Pivot<?>>> {
        public abstract TreeMultiset<? extends Pivot<T>> create();

        public abstract Comparator<? super T> comparator();

        public int compare(TreeMultiset<? extends Pivot<?>> t1, TreeMultiset<? extends Pivot<?>> t2) {
            // some code to compare multisets using comparator()
        }
    }
}
```

I currently have the following

```
class Entity {
    template<class T>
    class InputType {
    public:
        virtual multiset<class ExtendsPivot> create() = 0;

        virtual function<int(class SuperT, SuperT)> comparator() = 0;

        int compare(multiset<ExtendsPivot> &t1, multiset<ExtendsPivot> &t2);
    };
};

template<class T>
int Entity::InputType<T>::compare(multiset<ExtendsPivot> &t1, multiset<ExtendsPivot> &t2) { // error in InputType
    multiset<ExtendsPivot>::iterator
        iter1 = t1.begin(),
        iter2 = t2.begin();
    while ((iter1 != t1.end()) && (iter2 != t2.end())) { // error in iter1 != t1.end()
        // some code
    }
}
```

The header is ok (at least I think) but I would like to know if it can be done better. However, when I try to define `compare`, it hits the error `'InputType' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration`. Furthermore, `iter1 != t1.get()` gets the error `In template: field has incomplete type 'std::__tree_node<ExtendsPivot, void *>::__node_value_type' (aka 'ExtendsPivot')`. I'm confused on why the definition of compare is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
    template<class T>
    class InputType {
```

This declares a template.

```
int Entity::InputType::compare(multiset<ExtendsPivot> t1, multiset<ExtendsPivot> t2) { // error in InputType
```

`InputType` is not a class. It is a template class. Template class members must be declared accordingly, as templates:

```
template<typename T>
int Entity::InputType<T>::compare(multiset<ExtendsPivot> t1, multiset<ExtendsPivot> t2) {
```

and so on. In C++ definitions and declarations must "agree" with each other, in every detail.

This is going to address one of the causes of the ill-formed program, but the error message suggests that it's very likely that you will have more problems here. However it is not clear what the exact root causes are, since the shown code is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Finally, you should be cautioned that C++ is not Java, and objects in C++ work in fundamentally different ways than they do in Java. In particular, if `ExtendsPivot` is an abstract class, an attempt to create a multiset out of them (or any container) is guaranteed to end in tears. And if it's not an abstract class, then function or method parameters that are entire multisets of any kind will result in absolutely atrocious runtime performance, due to C++'s default by-value parameter passing. You will be surprised to learn that each call to this comparator function will result in automatically cloning (what cloning means in Java), both multisets, with every comparator call. And you don't have to do a thing, except to call the comparator. Bam, both multisets get cloned, automatically, courtesy of your C++ compiler. Amazing, isn't it?

In conclusion, C++ is not Java, and it is imperative to understand how C++ actually works fundamentally, before undertaking to translate anything of substance from a radically different language, like Java, into C++ in the most optimal and streamlined way. Ad hoc "searching and learning", I suspect, will not be enough. No amount of ad hoc "searching and learning" could possibly tell you, for example, that in this use case both multisets parameters should be passed ***by reference***. And not just any reference, but a ***constant reference***.

But that's mostly a moot point, because this kind of logic should be done using a completely different approach, anyway. I suspect that the above code can actually flush the `comparator()` down the drain, and simply use multisets with a custom comparator class (an entire class, not a function). C++ containers are not Java generics. Associative C++ containers can have their comparators "built-in" to them, with their modifiers using the custom comparator, without having to manually invoke some external comparator function, of some kind. If, as it seems, the purpose of that `compare()` is to implement a three-way comparison, with a custom comparator in place a `<=>` operator can be applied directly (in C++20) using native C++ syntax.

Translating Java into C++ line by line, like that, will always result in horrible, sub-optimal C++ code. It is imperative to, instead, analyze understand what each major component of a Java program does, and then implement, from scratch, using clean, native C++.

Comment: Ok, so as I mentioned already I'm new to C++ and am aware that it's different from Java. I did already learn about pass by reference vs pass by value but due to lack of experience, it wasn't on my mind. However 1) that's literally a one character fix and 2) it wasn't what I was asking about. Also, although I don't know C++, I've worked on the exact same project and have had 7 years of Java experience, and the project has long since been converging towards the optimal polymorphism. The comparator is needed to compare Pivots and said comparator is also used to compare TreeMultisets of Pivots.

Comment: What I'm wondering is how to achieve exactly the structure I've defined above. To make it clear, comparator() simply returns a ```Comparator<Pivot>``` used to compare single Pivot objects. In what I'm doing, there's only two static values of these comparators and the two implementations of InputType simply return them. The purpose of ```compare``` is to compare the ```Multiset<Pivot>```s, not the individual Pivots. I'm not using this compare method to further nest it in another Multiset. I just need this compare method for other purposes, exactly as it is.

Comment: In Java, one must manually implement functions to do native operations on classes, like comparing. In C++ we overload the operators themselves. Attempting to write Java in C++ results in unreadable code that no experienced C++ developer will understand. These kinds of topics, like operator overloading, and templates, is something a C++ developers learns only about 1-2 years into learning C++ from the ground up. Whether that C++ developer also knows Java makes no difference, C++ is not Java. There are no shortcuts to learning C++, it takes time.

Comment: I fail to see why knowing what Pivot is matters. It's literally just a class that can be compared and knowing what's in it has no relevance whatsoever. And Stackoverflow not being a tutorial site is true but is no excuse. Any knowledgeable person who actually tries to answer the original question instead of being a C++ salesman could have given a more informative answer that's at most as long as what you wrote. Seriously, can you spend your time and characters on useful answers?

Comment: Instead of saying
>In particular, if ExtendsPivot is an abstract class, an attempt to create a multiset out of them (or any container) is guaranteed to end in tears.
why not just say "making a multiset of an abstract class is bad because ..." and give the reason instead of spending 3 more paragraphs and not saying anything else useful. And it's not even bad, because an abstract class can contain all the necessary parameters and methods for any element you want to retrieve, and you can implement the necessary operator overrides

Comment: It is not just "bad". You cannot make a multiset of an abstract class, in C++, for a fairly basic, fundamental reason. The poor compiler will start throwing incomprehensible errors, hence the tear-soaked epilogue. You can in Java, but C++ is not Java, and objects in C++ work fundamentally differently than they do in Java. Containers (like multisets) of abstract classes must be designed as containers of unique_ptrs or shared_ptrs to abstract classes. This is why any moderately complex Java logic cannot just be translated into C++, line by line, verbatim; or even class by class.